# how to use a lookup to know the function to be executed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala map as below

val funcMap: Map(String,String)

```
(country_code, formatting_function_name)
(AU,function001)
(BH,function006)
(CN,function007)
(IN,function001)
```

On a given dataframe (indf),

```
id,country
001,AU
002,BH
003,CN
004,IN
```

I need to perform a lookup using this map and execute the function as returned with "id" as argument to get a column named, say "mapped_id".
eg. for AU -> mapped_id column should call function001("id")

```
indf.withcolumn("mapped_id",funcMap(col("country_code")))   //<- need to execute the returned function here eg: function001("id") to get the formatted value of id
```

these functions may be defined in a functions.scala file with different formatting logics
eg.

```
def function001(id:String): String = {
lpad(id,5,"0")
}

def function002(id:String): String = {
rpad(id,5,"0")
}
```

How do I call the function as per the name returned from the map?

Comment: Why have a `Map` of function names? instead of a `Map` of functions?

Comment: You mean the function logic be placed as the "value" in the map?
That is because the logic can be complicated and the design needs to be modular.
for eg: if 2 more countries need to be added to the MAP,
All that would be required is adding the country and the function name

``` 
(FI,function002)
(GB,function001)
```

going by what you mention, would it not require the logic to be replicated for every row of country at some place in the code?

Comment: `val funcMap: Map[String, String => String] = Map("AU", function001)` the code of `function001` can be anywhere and reuse as much logic as you want, I don't see what is the big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `Map` from `country_code -> formatting_function_name` means you need another layer of converting a function name to a function call. You can avoid this because in Scala functions are first-class entities, which means they can be passed around to other functions as parameters, because functions are objects.

A straightforward solution is to change your `Map` value type parameter according to the type of the formatting function. Here's what I mean:

```
val funcMap: Map[String, String => String]
```

Now you can create the formatted `String` for your `country_code` using:

```
indf.withcolumn("mapped_id", funcMap("country_code")("mapped_id"))
```

Here's a quick test:

```
object Something extends App {

  val Id = "someId"

  val Au = "AU"
  val Bh = "BH"
  val Cn = "CN"
  val In = "IN"

  def function001(id: String): String = s"$id function001"
  def function002(id: String): String = s"$id function002"
  def function003(id: String): String = s"$id function003"
  def function004(id: String): String = s"$id function004"

  val funcMap = Map[String, String => String](
    Au -> function001,
    Bh -> function002,
    Cn -> function003,
    In -> function004
  )

  println(funcMap(Au)(Id))
}
```

Outputs:

```
someId function001
```

Comment: Thanks. This did work for the requirements I had. Luis' answer was on similar lines too.